# Export C function from a C++/CLI DLL that uses .NET code

Tags: .net, c, interop, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI DLL that uses some managed code (written in C#). I want to export a pure C function from the DLL - it will be called from unmanaged code using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

In the exported function I just need to create an instance and call one method of a C# class. So I tried this:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int __stdcall DoWork(
       const wchar_t* Param1,
       int Param2,
       void* Param3)
{
    WorkerNamespace::ManagedClass1 worker;
    return worker.DoWork( gcnew String(Param1), Param2, IntPtr( Param3 ) );
}
```

It compiles fine but when I do a `dumpbin CompiledDll.dll /exports` there are no exported functions.

I tried adding `#pragma unmanaged` before the function declaration but then I get errors for using managed types inside the body.

If I replace the body of the function with an empty stub (just `return 1;`) and with `#pragma unmanaged`, the function **still** doesn't show up in `dumpbin`. So what am I doing wrong? How do I export a C function from a C++/CLI Class Library project?

Comment: header file is also important, also export function in `.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Must have been a configuration issue. I created a new project using the `Empty project` template, changed

`Configuration Type` to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`

`Common Language Runtime Support` to `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`

in General Configuration and added a reference to `System.Core` and my C# assembly in `Common Properties` and it works now.

I also added a .DEF file to handle name mangling (the def file's name should, of course, be set in `Linker -> Input -> Module Definition file`).

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
DoWork
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  What was the actual configuration issue?

Comment: @HansPassant Originally I created a project using the `Class Library` template. I don't know how that's different from what I posted. That's why it's still an open question.